# How to reset password without phone

Tags: gmail, account-management, account-recovery, passwords

My mobile phone has been stolen and I have blocked my number and bought a new sim with same mobile number. When I reset password and followed the instructions, it shows at the end of page:
Google could  not verify your account.

Please help me.

Comment: Would you follow the [instructions at Google](https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/41078) and tell us where you have the problem? [You'll want to be on the "Computer" Tab (not "Android" / "iPhone") if you don't have *any* cellphone] Your carrier can probably lend you a lousy free phone while you wait to get your lost phone back (or write it off), I am uncertain about the purpose of having a SIM (and possibly paying a monthly charge) without some cellphone to physically insert it into. In any event try that URL with your home computer and your original email account that you registered.

Answer (score -1):

You should use your recovery email.